# Pixastic and Jquery Tools

Tags: jquery, pixastic

I'm having an issue with pixastic and jquery tools overlay. I want overlay to open when an image is clicked and that image to be desaturated.

Desaturation and overlay work properly, but when the overlay is closed the image is not clickable anymore and does not revert back to the original color. Here is a test page (http://thesupercow.com/clients/overlaytest/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the page (http://thesupercow.com/clients/overlaytest/). I will create another page with pixastic and jquery on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Grayscale.js (http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/) is the answer, pixastic is great but I wasn't able to find a solution.

```
// turns all images on screen to grayscale
grayscale($("img"));

// reset images
grayscale.reset($("img"));
```

You can view the result here: http://thesupercow.com/clients/overlaytest/

Answer (score 0):

I too could not find the same for jquery, soe as per cosmoo's suggestion tried graysacle - worked for me!

```
grayscale($(".photo"));

$(".photo").hover(function () {
grayscale.reset(this);
},
function () {
grayscale(this);
});

grayscale.prepare($('.photo'));
```

cheers!

Comment: I tried and eventually removed both. They both work in the canvas method which is 1. not supported by chrome and also upsets the layout.